# How to use regex to remove string with only '11.x' pattern in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a list of values,

```
lst = ['python 3.x', 'java', 'pandas', '12.1.x/11.x', '7.x/8.x']
```

I want to replace the last two values with empty string `['12.1.x/11.x', '7.x/8.x']`

How can I use regex to replace them with empty strings which generalizes across similar pattern?

```
pattern = re.sub('\d+\.x\/\d+\.x', '', lst[3]) # this is not working
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want but try `[re.sub('.+\d+\.x$', '', item) for item in lst]`

Comment: I want to replace last two values with empty string. I want to replace the version pattern (i.e., 11.x or 12.1.x/11.x or 7.x and so on ) with empty string so I can remove them.

Comment: There's no `11.x` in `7.x/8.x` so asking for witchcraft is definitely off-topic here...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I just gave an example. I meant how to use regular expressions to catch the patterns like `12.1.x/11.x', '7.x/8.x` and replace them with empty string. It should not remove patterns like `JSP 11.x`

Comment: "Generalizes across similar pattern" is far too vague. Are you just looking to remove any strings that contain `".x"` as a substring?

Comment: @tzaman Yes but it should not remove values like `JSP 11.x or Python 3.x` but it should only remove if it contains only version number like `12.1.x or 7.x` etc.

Comment: @tzaman In the above list It should only replace the last two values with empty string. The regex should exclude things like python 2.x/3.x etc.,

Comment: Does there have to be an `x`? What about just `11.0`?

Comment: I'd suggest thinking carefully about exactly what kinds of patterns you want to accept and exclude, and drawing up a detailed list of examples and counterexamples. At that point you'll very likely be able to figure out the pattern you need yourself.

Comment: @tzaman Yes these values should get replaced with empty string `[12.1.x/11.x  or  7.x/8.x   or 12.1.1/11.0  or   7.1/8.1 ]` but it should exclude it it contains `[Python 3.7/2.3 or JSP 1.7]` etc.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure to use anchors and specify that a second version number is optional:

```
^(?:\d+\.)+(?:x|\d+)(?:/(?:\d+\.)+(?:x|\d+))?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/c0CDr5/1

I have no clue how to apply this correctly with Python so check out the Code Generator at the link above.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It is working at that website correctly.